# How to install Tensorflow version that suitibale whit Keras 3.0.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, installation

i want to install Tensorflow version greater than 2.16.0 for Keras 3.0.5, but i get an error: "No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.x.x".
I tried to uninstall Keras and Tensorflow and than install Tensorflow, but by default is 2.15.0 version.
My pyhton version is 3.10.9
Any suggestions how can i install this version of Tensorflow?
Thank you

Comment: try `pip install tf-nightly` for 2.16 (for the time being).

Comment: What device, operating system and what software are you going to use tensorflow? Your question is lacking info

Answer (score 0):

python -m venv myenv #creating environment exceptional!!
source myenv/bin/activate  # Activate the virtual environment
pip install tensorflow==2.17.0  # Install TensorFlow in the virtual environment